# Confused by UV Layers - why are they needed if an object can have UV's without them?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to come to grips with UV concepts in Blender, as someone coming from Autodesk products where there's the concept of UV-channels.
For now I'm assuming UV layers are like channels, meaning you can have different UV layouts on the same object coexist.
What I find very confusing, is that an object can have UV's, **without** having an explicit UV-Layer (an entry in the Mesh / UV Maps properties rollout). A new cube does come with a UV layer, but deleting is has no effect on it's UV's. Meshes created in Python with *bmesh* have UV's, without having a UV Layer.

Without this UV Layer I can't start editing from these existing UV's. Annoyingly, Blender seems to default to using these un-editable non-Layer UV's for all textures, meaning I have to take extra steps to explicitly use this UV layer for each texture. Compared to UV-channels in Max or Maya this seems so limited: you can always edit, clear or copy any channel in those apps. The default channel 0 is always used first by a material. I guess Blender is doing it different, to safeguard an object from ever having no UV's at all?

(additionally, I'd love to know if there is at least a way to edit or set this hidden, non-layer UV through python code with bmesh, or is it always locked..?)

Comment: `A new cube does come with a UV layer, but deleting is has no effect on it's UV's` This is not true, could you elaborate on why you think it is ?

Comment: "*an object can have UV's, without having an explicit UV-Layer (an entry in the Mesh / UV Maps properties rollout)*" How? Could you show where these "UV layer" are?

Comment: I was going to ask the same as @Gorgious - when I delete the default UV map of the default cube, it certainly has an effect on the UVs, and textures mapped to the default UV map will not show correct anymore. And the UV layout is not saved somewhere in the background either, because simply adding a new UV map with the "Plus" button does not bring the old layout back. And I don't know about UVs from _bmesh_, but if you for example create custom UV coordinates by storing data in an attribute in _Geometry Nodes_ you might not have a UV map either, but the coordinates in an attribute...

Comment: Hey, digging deeper it seems I am getting confused by the "Checker Texture". Apparently this isn't a true texture, as it looks like it can map to an object even if it has no UV's. I expected a "texture" to behave like a texture, not as a sort of semi-procedural...

Comment: ...well, when you talk about **procedural**, non-image textures, by default without plugging anything into the _Vector_ input they use _Generated_ coordinates, not UVs. Only the _Image Texture_ node uses a UV map by default - but also has a problem if none is present...

Comment: Right, I see. Look more closely, it seems like Checker Texture does an internal, non-uniform box UV projection.
Very much not a texture by my definition then, but I can live with that!

Comment: Yes it seems your confusion stems from having a biased definition of what a texture is :) A texture is a N (1, 2 ,3, ...) Dimensional image projected on a 3D surface, its definition is not directly tied to UVs. UVs are a means to project the texture on a surface, but the projection can be pretty much anything you can think of, procedural, box mapping, sphere mapping, etc. See [Texture Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping)

Comment: @Xoliul The _Checker Texture_ does not use an "_internal non-uniform box UV projection_". It uses _Generated_ coordinates which are normalized to going from 0 to 1 on each local axis. And other than image textures which are always 2-dimensional, procedural textures can be 1-, 2-, 3- and some even 4-dimensional. Maybe your definition of texture is limited to 2D bitmap images. A UV layout is always 2-dimensional, but the _Checker Texture_ actually uses 3 dimensions.

Comment: Ah but that's an age-old CG discussion ;) I had to look on Wikipedia a bit, but even there it also does suggest that "procedural textures" do get passed along as 2D files before they get mapped onto a 3D surface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping
We can discuss it all day long, I guess it's just part of Blender doing things a tad different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong. UVs actually work pretty much the same in Blender as in most other 3d packages. If you delete a UV layer of an object it is gone and can no longer be used or edited. You can use other types of texture coordinates if there are no UVs on an object:

[image]

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#outputs) for more about them. Most procedural textures use *Generated* texture coordinates by default, because unlike UVs those are 3D coordinates.

You can actually see part of the coordinates as color(limited to ranges from 0 to wherever they are cut off by color management) if you just connect them to the Material Output

[image]

UV layers in Blender are what UV Channels are in Max, that's just a different name. You can even import and export them between Blender and other software.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like my confusion came from Checker Texture using a form of generated coordinates over explicit UV's.

Comment: @Xoliul Your confusion might come from thinking the generated coordinates the _Checker Texture_ uses (which are the same generated coordinates all other procedural textures use) would have anything to do with any UV coordinates. But they haven't. It might only be that using some UV map layout results in the same or similar visual appearance as generated textures.

Comment: Yep. That is actually very useful when you work with procedural textures in Blender, because you can then manipulate a linear 3d coordinate system with math to deform procedural textures in 3d space in various ways.

Comment: Yes! Conclusion for me is: Other 3D applications most often clearly mean a 2D, bitmap file that exists in memory as such when they label something as "texture" (as is the case with the Checker in 3DS Max). In Blender this is not the case, and parametrically calculated and applied patterns are also labeled as textures. Only Blender's "Image Texture" would fit the definition I had in mind.

Comment: That's not really true. 3D textures exist in a lot of other software. They are a lot less commonly used just because of how widely used bitmap textures are. Volume or 3d textures is definitely a thing in most 3d packages. I am not extremely familiar with 3ds Max, but I would be surprised if that doesn't exist in it. I know for a fact, that Maya certainly has procedural 3d textures.

Comment: https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-0F4CC48B-8245-46C8-995D-43403C583EA3 You can clearly see that the term "texture" or "map" does not actually imply it being 2D. That's the confusion. Nothing to do with Blender being different in this case.